# I have a FPDF and I want to use money_format

Tags: php, fpdf

I created have the following and if I echo $CaRate I get the expected value but the pdf isn't generating when I put it in the cell.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$CaRate = money_format('%(#5n', $data[0]['data']['CarrierRate']) . "\n";

$pdf->Cell(30,8, $CaRate ,0,0,'L');
```

Comment: what is a sample $caRate you get?

Comment: $ 1,000.00 if I echo $CaRate and comment out the rest of the FPDF. the value of $data[0]['data']['CarrierRate'] is 1000.

Comment: can you generate pdf with a simple string in place of $,1000.00?

Comment: the PDF generates fine if I have my array value in place of $CaRate.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a win machine so money_format does not work. If I just hardcode `$caRate = $ 1,000.00` I am able to generate PDF without any issues

Comment: I must have messed something up when typeing. I went back and reset it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Cell(22,6,sprintf('%.2f',$BAmt),'B',0,'R',0);
```

detail: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24696443/I-need-to-know-how-to-format-currency-using-PHP-and-the-FPDF-library.html